¿Cómo se pueden dibujar en seaborn o matplotlib varias variables en el eje Y a la vez?
En el enunciado me piden lo siguiente: "Utilizando el archivo csv: COVID_01-01-2021, crea un programa que cree un gráfico de líneas en el que se muestre el total de casos confirmados, el total de casos fallecidos y el total de pacientes recuperados, y que compare sólo los países cuyo número de fallecidos sea superior a 150". No encuentro la manera de poder representar en el eje x los países cuyo números de fallecidos sea superior a 150 y en el eje y (en el mismo gráfico porque así me lo piden) representar las 3 variables( casos confirmados, total de fallecidos y total recuperados). He intentado varias cosas pero me dan todas error. Dejo por aquí una parte del documento y el código que estoy intentando desarrollar:

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/Alvaro/Desktop/Ejercicios Master Big Data y business intelligence/Documentos tema python/Trabajo final parte 2/COVID_01-01-2021.csv", sep = ",")

df_150 = list(df.loc[df["Deaths"] > 150, ["Country_Region", "Deaths"]])
df_2 = list(df["Confirmed"])
df_3 = list(df["Deaths"])
df_4 = list(df["Recovered"])

#plt.plot(df_2, c = "blue")
#plt.plot(df_3, c = "red")
#plt.plot(df_4, c = "green")

plt.plot(df_150, df_2 )
plt.plot(df_150, df_3 )
plt.plot(df_150, df_4 )


plt.show ()


Tu problema no es tanto con como generar la gráfica sino en como preparar los datos.
Tienes que tener solo en cuenta los paises con menos de 150 muertes, eso es lo que filtras en df_150, pero luego tomas todos los datos del dataframe original sin filtrar para los valores en Y (df_2, df_3 y df_4). Esto hace que el conjunto de datos para X tenga un tamaño distinto al del los conjuntos de datos a usar en Y.
Simplemente obten todas las columnas necesarias al filtrar tu DataFrame y usa esos datos para la gráfica:
df_150 = df.loc[
    df["Deaths"] > 150,
    ["Country_Region", "Confirmed", "Deaths", "Recovered"]
]


plt.plot(df_150["Country_Region"], df_150["Confirmed"], label="Confirmed", c="blue")
plt.plot(df_150["Country_Region"], df_150["Deaths"], label="Deaths", c="red")
plt.plot(df_150["Country_Region"], df_150["Recovered"], label="Recovered", c="green")

plt.legend()
plt.show()

O usa pandas.DataFrame.plot() directamente:
df_150 = df.loc[
    df["Deaths"] > 150,
    ["Country_Region", "Confirmed", "Deaths", "Recovered"]
]


df_150.plot(
    x="Country_Region",
    y=["Confirmed", "Deaths", "Recovered"],
    color=["blue", "red", "green"]
)

No termino de verle el sentido a usar un grafico de lineas para representar estos datos, pero bueno...
Una observación, te piden que muestres en el eje X los paises, pero si miramos tus datos de ejemplo tus datos por pais están separados por regiones. Con tu código actual graficas regiones (8 para Australia por ejemplo), posiblemente deberias agrupar y sumar los datos de un mismo pais (sumar los valores de todas sus regiones) y usar esos datos para graficar. En este caso simplmente tienes que usar pandas.DataFrame.groupby(), algo como:
country_group = (
    df[["Country_Region", "Confirmed", "Deaths", "Recovered"]]
        .groupby(["Country_Region"])
        .sum()
)
country_group[country_group["Deaths"] > 150].plot(color=["blue", "red", "green"])


Muchas gracias como siempre por la explicación tan detallada. Ahora consigo entender el problema que tenía respecto a representar información con tamaños distintos. En cuanto al sentido del gráfico de líneas.. pues bueno, supongo que no están los ejercicios pensados bien al 100%. Por otro lado, te quería preguntar, al representar la primera gráfica, me salen los nombres apelotonados y no se ve nada, se podrían cambiar de posición en vez de en horizontal, en diagonal? Un saludo y muchas gracias!

@AlvaroGarciaLinares Recuerda que puedes aceptar una respuesta si es que ésta te ha ayudado a resolver el problema
